# SQL Replication - What is @frequency_recurrence_factor and what must it be set to?

Tags: sql-server, replication

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addpublication-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says:

> [ @frequency_recurrence_factor = ] frequency_recurrence_factor Is the
> recurrence factor used by frequency_type. frequency_recurrence_factor
> is int, with a default of 0.

Does this mean the frequency_recurrence_factor has to equal what the frequency_type is? I don't know what the numbers mean for frequency_recurrence_factor and I couldn't find any definitive answer on it.

I have 2 sp_addpublication_snapshot lines of code, one with the frequency type of 8, and the other with a FT of 4.  What should my frequency interval be?

Code:

```
EXEC sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'publicationName', @frequency_type = 8, @frequency_interval = 1, @frequency_relative_interval = 1, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 1, @frequency_subday_interval = 1, @active_start_time_of_day = 090000, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 0, @job_login = N'user', @job_password = 'password', @publisher_security_mode = 1;
```

Error:

*The schedule for this job is invalid (reason: @freq_recurrence_factor must be at least 1.)*

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The way that I read the doc is that for instance freq type 8 means weekly basis, freq interval 1 means Sunday and recurrance factor 2 (for instance) would mean every *other* week, 3 means every third week, etc.

Comment: You're trying to create Snapshot replication Publications, right?